# Google login failure with Firebase, while Facebook and email login was successful

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-authentication, keytool

I got this error code

E/flutter (24478): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

and tried many options

1. reinstall the google service file;
2. re generate the debugstore, and reinstall the SHA1 and SHA256 certificates
3. build different apps with similar login method:
   final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

So far no one option success. :(

Comment: [mcve].........

Answer (score 0):

finally I found out myself that the debug key was not generated correctly, and I used the wrong SHA1. After finding out the debug keystore location, and generated the key accordingly, the problem resolved.

PS D:\sam_flutter_project\pictorial_groupbuy_v3> keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\notebook.android\debug.keystore"